# Authorization failed for Microsoft App Id

Tags: .net, botframework

I've started seeing this error for the last few hours.

Authorization for Microsoft App ID {{AppGuid}} failed with status code Unauthorized

```
var dataBag = scope.Resolve<IBotData>();
await dataBag.LoadAsync(cancellationToken);
int magicNumber = GenerateRandomNumber();
dataBag.UserData.SetValue(Constants.AuthResultKey, authResult);
dataBag.UserData.SetValue(Constants.MagicNumberKey, magicNumber);
dataBag.UserData.SetValue(Constants.MagicNumberValidated, "false");
await dataBag.FlushAsync(cancellationToken); <---- Fails here!
```

I tried generating a new secret key and used that as well, but no luck.

Anyone else seeing this issue?

Thanks, Izaaz

Answer (score 1):

Figured the issue. The new IDialog class I had created was not marked as Serializable.